# Disable regex in Lucene search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

How I could disable regex in Lucene search?
My problem is when I search something like that `32/22-ЕКТ` I cant't find anything.
It's working just when I write in quotes like this `"32/22-ЕКТ"` or `32\/22-ЕКТ`
It's because slashes are used as beginning/end or a regex query in search field.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to disable it. You can switch from Lucene to KQL, this way regex won't be automatically enabled.